# Causes for IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jsp, illegalstateexception, tomcat5.5

I'm getting IllegalStateException from Tomcat server, when I try to save a JSP's data in EXCEL. `IllegalStateException` can occur in any of the following condition:

- If there is no return statement after `sendRedirect()`.
- If POST size is greater than 2MB.
- If page buffer size is less.

Other than this, is there any causes for `IllegalStateException`?

My code:

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getRequestURI() + "?saveToFile=true&action=" + ReportsManager.ACTION_SAVE_AS_XLS + "&saveFileName=" + saveFileName + "&returnPage=" + StringFunctions.encodeUrlParameter(returnPage)));    
return;
```

I'm getting `IllegalStateException` at sendRedirect().

Also if there are only few records (say 100 rows) in JSP, then there is no error in saving as Excel. If there is 1000 records, then I'm getting `IllegalStateException`.

Stack trace:

```
*Mar 25, 2013 6:57:26 AM,JSP Runtime Error,0,java.lang.IllegalStateException
       at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteResponseFacade.sendRedirect(CoyoteResponseFacade.java:352)
       at org.apache.jsp.OperationalReports.SalespersonSales_jsp._jspService(SalespersonSales_jsp.java:2567)
       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
       at com.retailJava.core.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:136)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
       at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

If I set page buffer size, then it worlks fine for 1000 records. But if it reaches 2000 records, then again I'm getting issue.

```
<%@ page buffer = "2048kb" autoFlush = "true" %>
```

Comment: The possiblities are limitless. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html

Comment: Why don't you show relevant code ? It might help more.

Comment: Added my code, which causes the issue.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: what do you exactly mean with *"save a JSP's data in EXCEL"*?

Comment: Save a JSP's data in EXCEL means, the dbquerry, executed from JSP, will return list of rown, which will be displayed in JSP as a table. Upon clicking on save button, the data will be saved as Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) states:

> **sendRedirect** Throws: IllegalStateException - if this response has already been committed

Since disabling the maxPostSize does not solve the problem (according to OP comments) it seems that at an earlier point the responce is beeing commited.

You can verify this by checking the [isCommited](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.html#isCommitted%28%29) flag.

Comment: Is there a way to fix the issue? From Tomcat configuration document I got the below suggestion: We can add the following property in Tomcat’s server.xml “maxPostSize”. By default this will be set to 2MB. By setting this to 0, we can disable the size check. But this does not seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks dude. As you said Response is getting commited if there is a large data. :) Need to verify why its getting comitted.

Answer (score 2):

If you call twice "response.sendRedirect()" method,
or url is a wrong url,this error may cause

Answer (score 0):

Encounter the same error in different use case.

[image]

**Use Case :** In Hibernate, when we try to access any method on session object after closing the session intentionally.

```
Session session = /*Getting session object using factory*/
tx = session.beginTransaction();
System.out.println("Flush Mode before closing session -> " +session.getFlushMode());

session.close();
System.out.println("Flush Mode after closing session -> " + session.getFlushMode());
```

**Key Point**

- IllegalStateException occur due to method invocation at in appropriate time
- In context of session, we can't call any method of session once it is closed